# Comparing field to itself in DAX and Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following data about ownership of barbers in three barber shops

[image]

I'm interested presenting a matrix on PBI where the rows are barbers that are owners in at least one barber shop and the columns are all barbers. Each cell in the matrix to represent relationship between the barbers when they're owners and the rest of the barbers. If two barbers own a barbershop their relationship is "owners" even if other barber shop one of them is tenant. If the second barber is always a tenant in owner's barber shop than it's a owner-tenant relationship. Same barber is "same person". Any other relationship remains blank.

I expect the following result:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample of some of the code you've written already?

Comment: Actually I got stuck right in the beginning of presenting the same field twice on the matrix. I tried to make two other tables that contain the owners and all the barbers to put them in the matrix but then I couldn't reach the right DAX to present them

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the query editor, your row data is Barber and I named the new table "BarberMatrix":

```
let
    Source = Barber,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Status] = "Owner")),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows", {"BarberShop"}, Barber, {"BarberShop"}, "Barber.1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Barber.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Barber.1", {"Barber", "Status"}, {"Resource", "ResStatus"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Barber.1", "StateData", each if [Barber] = [Resource] then "Same Person" else if [ResStatus] = "Owner" then "Owners" else "Owner-Tenant")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Next thing is to bring this in a matrix visual:

[image]

I took the subtotals out and it looks exactly what you there looking for..